# Vue redirecting response data into vue object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm successfully getting my response data pushed into my `dateEvents` return in the vue block below. I also have successfully rendering `events` for a calendar package I'm using. What I really want to do is get my response data to the events object (I want `response.data` `name` to be my events `title` and `response.data` `available_at` to equal events `start`).

So to clarify, my response data is the following: `[name:"test one", available_at:"2019-09-25"][name:"test two", available_at:"2019-09-25"]`, so I want take the `response.data` that I'm pushing to my `events` array and use `name` as `title` and `available_at` as `start`. I'm definitely getting the data and able to render the `dateEvents` but I'm just not sure how to direct them into this format for events.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dateEvents: [],
      events: [
        {
          title: 'test',
          start: '2019-08-17',
        },
        {
          title: 'another test',
          start: '2019-08-20',
        },
      ],
      config: {
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
          console.log(event)
        },
      },
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchTasks()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchTasks() {
      axios
        .get('/dashboard/tasks')
        .then(response => {
          // handle success
          console.log(response.data)
          this.dateEvents = response.data
          this.events = response.data
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error)
        })
        .finally(function() {})
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new array with objects that match your scheme. Look a the code below. We are mapping through the response and creating a new object on each iteration, that contains `title` as `item.name` and `start` as `item.item.available_at`.

```
.then((response) => {
  // handle success
  console.log(response.data);
  const events = response.data.map(item => {
    return {
      title: item.name,
      start: item.available_at
    };
  });

  this.dateEvents = events;
  this.events = events;
})
```

Comment: this did work, thank you! Am I able to do conditionals here though? Like 'if type === '3' ' to only load those into events? I'm wondering if I can dictate here which ones I load to dateEvents and which go to events